# how to detect the scrolling to the end of a page in Firefox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with this jQuery script:
What I want to do is trigger a function when the end of the page is reached.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight ) { 
        // Display alert or whatever you want to do when you're 
        // at the bottom of the page. 
        if (autoscroll == 1) {
            $('#loadMore').trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

But why is this code not working on Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $("body").height())
    { 
        $('#loadMore').trigger('click');
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried this method and still doesn't solve my problem...you can see it here at http://www.theworldsmiling.com
Works on Chrome and Safari, but FFX doesn't...

Comment: I just tested on firefox and it is working, what version of firefox are you using?

BTW there is some errors related to something called container.tzShutter, check the javascript console.

Comment: Maybe you have javascript disabled on Firefox or something? Here is a little video of it working on latest Firefox (Windows 7): http://i.imgur.com/ngVZH.gif BTW, you still have not fixed the issues i told you.

Comment: I know, I don't have much time right now, and I haven't built that script...I shall have a look at it soon!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with the above answer. Here is the version that worked for me:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
    // At the bottom of the frame
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that it's better to use `window.innerHeight` instead of `$(window).height()` because of different behaviour between Chrome and Firefox